# Ionic 3 : how to parse data from pushed array

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Ok so I followed a tutorial onto how to receive JSON replies and put them into an [] on Ionic and I managed to do that successfully. I stored the response into a this.infoList (declared in class 'infoList = []') and when console logging it it looked as it had all the data as follows(Sorry hid the data but is for illustration):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5JsA.png

the code I used to push it was:
this.navCtrl.push(ResultPage,this.infoList);

the code I used in result.ts's constructor to attempt to log one of the details for example id was:
console.log(navParams.get('id'));

yet it always comes out first on console and comes out as undefined, please point me in the right direction <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.infoLlist appears to be an array.

Option 1 - Pass the first item in the array as a nav param:

```
this.navCtrl.push(ResultPage,this.infoList[0]);
// then you should be able to do this in the constructor
console.log(navParams.get('id'));
```

Option 2 - Pass the entire array as a nav param by wrapping it in an object literal:

```
this.navCtrl.push(ResultPage,{infoList: this.infoList});
//then you should be able to do this in the constructor
console.log(navParams.get('infoList')[0].id);
```